# What makes an IoC container an IoC container?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, service-locator

So..I've been digging into IoC container and service locator.

I thought an IoC container is an IoC container, not a service locator because

1. The way you use it. You pass a service locator to a class that needs dependencies and then retrieve a dependencies via the container. On the other hand, you inject dependencies to your class using IoC container.
2. IoC containers support auto-wiring, whereas service locators don't.

I always thought that IoC containers support auto-wiring and it has to support it to be called an IoC container, but I had a conversion with some people who told me that IoC container doesn't have to support auto-wring.

If that's true, what makes an IoC container an IoC container except the way you use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A DI Container is a library that you can use in various ways:

- The simplest (pseudo) DI Container you can write is basically juts a **glorified dictionary**. You can [build one in 15 lines of code](http://ayende.com/blog/2886/building-an-ioc-container-in-15-lines-of-code). However, it doesn't do Auto-Wiring, which means that it doesn't do composition, so at this point you can only use it as a Service Locator, but since [Service Locator is an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern), there's not much benefit from that.
- A better DI Container also does **Auto-Wiring**. As soon as it can do Auto-Wiring, you can also use it as a Composition Engine. This means that you can design your own code exclusively on container-agnostic patterns like Constructor Injection, and then in the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot) ask the Composition Engine (DI Container) to compose everything together.

As soon as a DI Container supports Auto-Wiring, you can *use* it in [both ways](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Succeeding-Dependency-Injection), but you should only use it as a Composition Engine.

Since Service Locator is an anti-pattern, the glorified dictionary has no value. As a bare minimum then, I'd say that a library **must support Auto-Wiring in order to be a DI Container**. However, that still doesn't make it a *valuable* component. To derive value from a DI Container, [it must support sophisticated convention-based heuristics](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer); if it doesn't, you're better off writing the composition by hand (AKA *Poor Man's DI*).

Comment: Wait a minute...you're the author of dependency injection in .net, which I ordered last night while researching on this topic lol. Thank you so much for the write up.